# Cannot import name views

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views, django-1.7

```
ImportError at /

cannot import name views

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version:     1.7
Exception Type:     ImportError
Exception Value:    

cannot import name views

Exception Location:     /Users/adam/Desktop/qblog/qblog/urls.py in <module>, line 1
Python Executable:  /Users/adam/Desktop/venv/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.8
Python Path:    

['/Users/adam/Desktop/qblog',
 '/Users/adam/Desktop/venv/lib/python27.zip',
 '/Users/adam/Desktop/venv/lib/python2.7',
 '/Users/adam/Desktop/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/Users/adam/Desktop/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/Users/adam/Desktop/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Users/adam/Desktop/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/Users/adam/Desktop/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/Users/adam/Desktop/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Users/adam/Desktop/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages']

Server time:    Sun, 21 Sep 2014 15:12:22 +0000
```

Here is urls.py located in qblog/qblog/:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from . import views


urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^markdown/', include('django_markdown.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('blog.urls')),
)
```

Also, if I add "library" to the first import statement (which I don't need) it will give me the same error but with library, "Cannot import name library".

Here is urls.py located in qblog/blog/:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^$', views.BlogIndex.as_view(), name="index"),
)
```

Going to the url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/index` provides the same error.

I do not get any errors in the terminal when running `./manage.py runserver`

Project structure:

```
.
├── blog
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
│   │   ├── 0002_auto_20140921_1414.py
│   │   ├── 0002_auto_20140921_1414.pyc
│   │   ├── 0003_auto_20140921_1501.py
│   │   ├── 0003_auto_20140921_1501.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── qblog
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── blog.css
│   │   └── bootstrap.min.css
│   ├── icons
│   │   └── favicon.ico
│   └── js
│       ├── bootstrap.min.js
│       └── docs.min.js
└── templates
    ├── base.html
    ├── home.html
    └── post.html
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no need to import the views in your project-level file. You are not using them there, so no reason to import them.

If you *did* need to, you would just to `from blog import views`, because the views are in the blog directory and manage.py puts the top-level directory into the Python path.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. But, I get "name 'admin' is not defined" when the views import statement is removed.

Comment: That's because you don't have `from django.contrib import admin` which you should have.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `import views`.This works for me

Comment: What difference does it make when I remove `from .`.
Will I face any problem developing my project furthur ?