# Django Python - import error: No module named 'views'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am trying to run a webserver in Django using this tutorial series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rpi0Ne1nMdk&list=PLPSM8rIid1a3TkwEmHyDALNuHhqiUiU5A

I get an error when I try and import the script 'landing.views' inside urls.py, here is the error in it's entirety:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 224, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\trevo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'views'
```

Here is the code that generates the error seen above in urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path 
from landing.views import Index

urlpatterns = [
    path('', Index.as_view(), name='index'),
]
```

I have also tried looking at posts that other users have created like these: [ImportError: cannot import name 'Index' from 'landing.views'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69379878/importerror-cannot-import-name-index-from-landing-views), [Django error in urlpatterns: No module named views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32754839/django-error-in-urlpatterns-no-module-named-views), [Cannot import name views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25960754/cannot-import-name-views), however, the first link is currently not answered, and the latter few are not really related to the code that I am currently using. I have also tried other methods like using
`sys.path.insert(1, 'C:/Users/trevo/OneDrive/Desktop/VegaAiTest/ChattingPlatform/src/VegaPlatform/landing/urls.py')` and `sys.path.append("C:/Users/trevo/OneDrive/Desktop/VegaAiTest/ChattingPlatform/src/VegaPlatform/landing/urls.py")` as well as using the `SET PYTHONPATH=` command in my powershell application. What exactly am I doing wrong that might be causing these errors? Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `views.py` from project directory to application directory. If you don't understand the difference, show me `ls -laR` output.

Have you renamed site from `landing` to something else? Update `from landing.views import Index` if so.

Comment: I'm not sure what the ls -laR  command is exactly but I have the ls output: Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        10/20/2021  11:37 PM                landing
d-----        10/20/2021  11:37 PM                social
d-----        10/20/2021  11:30 PM                templates
d-----        10/19/2021  11:17 AM                VegaPlatform
-a----        10/20/2021  11:58 PM         143360 db.sqlite3
-a----        10/19/2021  11:17 AM            690 manage.py

Answer (score 0):

- Solution 1

  ```
       import landing.views

       ​urlpatterns​ ​=​ [
       path​(​''​, ​landing​.​views​.​Index.as_view()​, ​name​=​'index'​),
      ]
  ```
- Solution 2

  ```
  from landing.views import Index

  ​urlpatterns​ ​=​ [
  path('index/', views.Index.as_view(),name='index'),
  ]
  ```
- Solution 3: Inside landing app create `urls.py` an add

  ```
  from views import Index

  ​urlpatterns​ ​=​ [
  path('index/', views.Index.as_view(),name='index')
  ]
  ```

and in `project/urls.py` add

​

```
from​ ​django​.​urls​ ​import​ ​include​, ​path

    ​urlpatterns​ ​=​ [
    path('landing/', include('landing.urls') ),
    ]
```